# Use SharedPreferences to set the class value for an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

One of the screens in my app has a button that takes the user to a different screen. The destination screen is determined by a preference stored in SharedPreferences. How do I set the class of the Intent from shared preferences?

This is currently what I have for the button:

```
case R.id.favoriteButton1:
                final Intent favorite1Screen = new Intent();
                favorite1Screen.setClass(this, prefs.getString("favorite1Class", ""));
                startActivity(favorite1Screen);
                break;
```

And this is one of the screens where that preference can be set:
case R.id.action_favorite_1:

```
            final SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences("myDataStorage", MODE_PRIVATE);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor nEditor = prefs2.edit();

            nEditor.putString("favorite1Text", "Job Hazard Analysis");
            nEditor.putString("favorite1Color", "Safety");
            nEditor.putString("favorite1Intent", "Job_Hazard_Analysis");
            nEditor.commit();

            break;
```

The intent clearly won't accept a string value to set its class, is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: I do not recommend this. Using outside input to *directly* create a class name opens up security issues. Use some sort of validation logic to map from your string to a Java `Class` (e.g., static `HashMap<String, Class>`), to be able to ignore unexpected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even setup the context and class from the Intent constructor like this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);`

You can keep doing it with the setClass method though. I think the error though might be in how the class reference is interpreted.

I think probably your class name string must be a fully qualified class name. Mean the package and all must be explicited. Like:

```
`com.mypackage.myclass_name`
```

Then once you have that one in the Shared Preferences, you can try:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, 'com.mypackage.myclass_name');`

or if that doesn't work try:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName('com.mypackage.myclass_name'));`

Comment: I've attempted all these methods, however the issue still remains that it doesn't accept a string as a valid input method to assign the class name.

Comment: My apologies I was making a simple error that actually did solve the problem.

Comment: @xander Good to know. Good luck there.